# C# Await, null-coalescing, string interpolation does not compile

Tags: c#, async-await, string-interpolation, null-coalescing-operator

When conditionally awaiting a task using the null coalescing operator inside a string interpolation, I got an unexpected compilation error that my async method lacks an await, and that await isn't possible outside of an async context:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Task<string> isNull = null;
        var result = "World";
        var helloWorld = $"Hello {await (isNull ?? Task.FromResult(result))}";
        Console.WriteLine(helloWorld);
    }
}
```

```
Compilation error (line 10, col 29): The name 'await' does not exist in the current context
Compilation error (line 6, col 27): This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
```

I assume this is due to some compilator details that I am not aware of, and can't be avoided, but I would like to understand it.

[Link to fiddle describing issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PQ2XTo)

Comment: Why don't you just introduce a new variable with the result of `await (isNull ?? Task.FromResult(result))` and then use that in the interpolation?

Comment: @phuzi That works, I am not looking for a work-around, there are several possible, I want to understand why the code does not compile.

Comment: It looks to me like you've managed to confuse the parser. Maybe worth an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you encountered a roslyn bug: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39149

Comment: Thanks for the link, then I won't report it either.

Comment: You could add youe exact test case to the bug.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much point -- the reproducer in that issue is a simplified version of OP's